# Change mapping of XML files in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, url-routing

I want to serve my `sitemap.xml` dynamically, but every `.xml` file is mapped to static content in my Spring Boot application.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sitemap.xml", produces = MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String xmlSitemap() {
    HashSet<String> uris = new HashSet<>();
    // add Strings
    return SitemapCreator.createSitemapFromRelativeLinks(uris,"https://domain.tld");
}
```

Everytime I open `http://localhost:8080/sitemap.xml` it throws a 404. If the value of `RequestMapping` is changed to "/sitemap" it works.